# Create a class to load an image from url xamarin android

Tags: c#, xamarin.android

I try create  a class by using async Tack but I can't do it.  I have some problem with my code. I don't know what I should put in the DoInBackground inthe the OnPostExecute and in the MainAvctivity.cs.
I'm begginner in Xamarin android and in C# and I'm a student. Someone can help me

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

using Android.App;
using Android.Content;
using Android.Graphics;
using Android.OS;
using Android.Runtime;
using Android.Views;
using Android.Widget;
using Java.Lang;
using Java.Net;

namespace TestImageURL3._0  
{
class ImageURL : AsyncTask<URL, int, ImageView>
{
    ImageView bitmapImage=null;


    public ImageURL(ImageView bitmapImage)
    {
        this.bitmapImage = bitmapImage;
    }

    protected override Java.Lang.Object DoInBackground(params Java.Lang.Object[] @params)
    {
        this.bitmapImage = (ImageView)bitmap[0];
        string URL = (string)bitmap[1];
        return URL;
    }

    protected override void OnPostExecute(Java.Lang.Object result)
    {
        var imageView = FindViewById<ImageView>(Resource.Id.imageView1);
        var uri = Android.Net.Uri.Parse(uriString: "http://www.qygjxz.com/data/out/244/4304228-wallpaper-phone-hd.jpg");
        imageView.SetImageBitmap(uri);
    } 
}
}
```

Comment: Hello Melissa, welcome to StackOverflow! Please do not post your code as an image as many people cannot access imgur from their network. Code should always be transcribed into the body of your question. In addition, you've only tagged `xamarin.android` for your question, while it would probably benefit from a C# tag as well. Also, check out [How To Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) so that you can improve your question and be more likely to receive an answer. As it stands now, with your question is likely to be deleted/downvoted because it is very low quality.

Answer (score 0):

You should consider using an async image loading library like [FFImageLoading](https://github.com/luberda-molinet/FFImageLoading) or [Glide](https://github.com/beraybentesen/glide-xamarin-android). Both of those libraries will handle the async loading of an image from a url for you with very little overhead.

I know this doesn't exactly answer your question, but it is a much easier solution than what you're trying to accomplish. Good luck!